# Safest way to save data for paginating a query

Tags: php, cookies, pagination

I have a query which uses a list of IDs as input (eg. "WHERE XX IN (1,2,3,4) ) and the results are too many to be shown on a single web page. What I plan to do is to limit the results and paginate them. With MySql I added "LIMIT X OFFSET Z".

My problem is now how to pass the information to every single page. I could generate the pagination links with the list of IDs in it (eg. `<a href='link.php?i=1,2,3&page=1>1</a>` ) or I could store them somewhere. Since I'm using php I was thinking to use SESSION to store them or write them in a cookie for now. Using a DB is overkill? I can make a simple solution with cookies for now and change it later. Having IDs in a cookie isn't a security problem. Even if an user add ids to that list doesn't matter.

There are some answer on SO, but none seems to address all various possibilities.

Comment: I would suggest using javascript to do the pagination

Comment: Do you have an example? From what I understand is basically like having all info on the link's href, but instead of writing ids 20 times, I just write them somewhere and get it with a javascript command.

Comment: @gbestard while I agree with javascript for pagination in the browser, he has to write the pagination logic in his backend code first. Javascript won't do any good to the load and data transfer if on each request the server is returning some tens of thousands of records ;)

Comment: @mobinoob I wrote some example code for including pagination info in the query string. This should solve your problem, but if you'd like to go the session way let me know.

Comment: @Oerd true, just javascript would not be enough if we're talking about tens of thousands of records but for a few hundreds it would be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the database is overkill. Depending on you web app both Session and URL are good ways to solve this.

I think that the best solution of these two is to include pagination in the URL. This will help a lot when sharing links to your app. (Immagine sending a co-worker a link to a page in your app... and you are using sessions for pagination)

Have a constant in your code for the "page size" and then multiply it by the page number in the query string to get the offset. Here is a simplified code sample to illustrate:

```
<?php
    $limit = 30; // records per page to have more/less change this
    $page = 0;   // if not set, $page is 0 (first page)
    if (isset($_GET['page']) {
        $page = (int)$_GET['page']; // cast to int, to drop funny chars etc.
    }
    $offset = $page * $limit;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE some_col IN (1,2,3,4)";

    // ... then, to add offset data to your query:
    $query += " LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset"; // mind the single space
```

Your links then should include the `page` arg: `echo "link.php?i=1,2,3&page=".$page+1;` incrementing for next page (or have a loop for printing links to the next `n` pages).

A word of **warning**:

- Do not use cookies to store pagination data. Cookies are data that needs to be sent (sometimes unnecessarily) back-and-forth between request-response lifecycles. And you shouldn't trust cookies in the first place ;)
- It looks like your are getting the data for `WHERE XX IN (1,2,3,4)` from your query string. Be aware that doing this wrong, leaves you wide open to sql injection.

Comment: Ids are indeed from the user input. There is no other way. User select stuff, the page memorize the IDs and then I send them to the query to get results. I use a stored procedure and check for injection. Storing ids in a cookie or putting them in the links is equally unsafe :)

Comment: I just wanted to give you a heads-up, this is not necessarily "unsecure" ;)

Comment: When php casts to int it will drop any non-numeric chars, so splitting at `,` and casting to int in a loop will go a long way

Comment: For single values I've read about the +0 trick  $intval= $postval +0

Comment: yeah, but it's a trick (ever tried `i=1,2.5,3`?). Casting is semantically better. And your code will tell whoever reads it that you *wanted* to convert a string to an int.

Comment: half agree. I am converting IDs. they must be integer. Speed is more important.

Comment: having worked with php+mysql I can tell you that casting or adding zero is the last place you should look to increase performance (don't quote me on this, but I think adding zero implies first casting a string to int, than adding 0)

Comment: anyway, didn't mean to turn this into an outright chat :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55815/discussion-between-oerd-and-mobinoob).